# Semantically splitted quote in html

Tags: html, css

What is the best practice to make block quote but the text is not all in one line
here is an image to clarify what i mean

[image]

how to achieve this layout ? and is it also possible if i use h1 for the text inside the block quote since this is the main header of the website ?

here is what i did

```css
div {
    font-size: 5vw;
}

img {
    position: relative;
    top: -2vw;
    z-index: -1;
}

.bottom {
    position: relative;
    top: -5.5vw;
}
```

```html
<blockquote>
    <div class="top">
        the quick <br>
        brown fox
    </div>
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1560809451-9e77c2e8214a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="">
    <div class="bottom">
        jumps over <br>
        the lazy dog.
    </div>
</blockquote>
```

Comment: try adding `line-height: 5vw` to `div`.

Comment: Can you explain what you want in more detail?

Comment: @SafwanSamsudeen I'm asking if my approach to achieve the layout is semantically correct, since i have a text inside div is it better i wrap everything inside the block quote in an h1 or to make it more simple how would you create this layout ?

Comment: As you can see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/HTML/Element/blockquote) `Blockquote` can contain `<h1>` tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The **HTML [`<blockquote>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/blockquote) Element** (or HTML Block Quotation Element) indicates that the enclosed text is an extended quotation.

I'm not sure why you want to use a `blockquote` if `this is the main header of the website`.

```css
header {
  font-size: 2rem;
  line-height: 0.8;
  max-width: 200px;
}
header * {
  display: block;
}
header .top, header .bottom {
  position: relative;
}
header .top {
  top: 0.5em;
}
header .bottom {
  bottom: 0.5em;
}

.sr-only {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: -1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<header class="page-header">
  <h1 class="sr-only">The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</h1>
  <span class="top" aria-hidden="true">The quick brown fox</span>
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1560809451-9e77c2e8214a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=200&q=60" alt="Cool but very serious fox getting ready to jump">
  <span class="bottom" aria-hidden="true">Jumps over the lazy dog.</span>
</header>

<main>
  <p>Other content</p>
</main>
```